# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4 - multivariate timeseries data

Tags: r, keras, time-series, lstm

I have multivariate timeseries data with 100,000 rows and currently 32 features (the features will be reduced later).

I've already tried to use    layer_flatten.    as other suggested it on github. Unfortunately didn't work for me.

The error is generated whe I try to build the keras model.

This is my code:

```
lstm_v1 <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_lstm(units = 32, input_shape = c(nrow(data), 1, ncol(data)), batch_size = nrow(data), return_sequences = T) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

lstm_v1 %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
  optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
   metrics = c('accuracy')
)

summary(lstm_v1)

hist_lstm_v1 <- lstm_v1 %>% fit(
  x = as.matrix(data), y = km_dt$cluster, batch_size = nrow(spg_tt_1_scaled), verbose = 2
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras LSTM layer expects the input to be `3` dims as `(batch_size, seq_length, input_dims)`, but you have assigned it wrong. Try this

```
layer_lstm(units = 32, input_shape = c(seq_length, 32), batch_size = batch_size, return_sequences = T)
```

You need to reshape your data to three dims, where new dims will represent the sequential data.

I used toy dataset to show an example, here data and labels are of shape `((150, 32), (150,))` initially, using the following script:

```
seq_length = 10 # choice
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, 150 - seq_length, 1):
    dataX.append(data[i:i+seq_length])
    dataY.append(labels[i+seq_length-1])
import numpy as np
dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (-1, seq_length, 32))
dataY = np.reshape(dataY, (-1, 1))
# dataX.shape, dataY.shape
```

Output: `((140, 10, 32), (140, 1))`

Now you can safely feed it to model.

Comment: Ty and sry for my late answer. My exams got between me and this comment. As you said the input_shape was wrong and I needed to reshape my data before using the fit function. Would give you a +1 but my reputation is too low for that. XD